# Age select select box without array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way of creating an age select list like this:

```
<?php
$Array = array('99','98','97','96');
?>
<select name="age">
<option value="" selected>Choose</option>
<?php foreach($Array as $value){ echo('<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>');}?>
</select>
```

but without a really long array as I want age range to be from say 18 upto 100 and that would take forever to writeout?

Comment: Writing out everything? That would kinda defeat the whole purpose of programming lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a basic `for` loop:

```
<?php 
for($value = 18; $value <= 100; $value++){ 
    echo('<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>');
}
?>
```

Comment: @Dizzi would you care to mark the answer as the correct solution

Comment: Sorry quite new here ...Done :)

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a [range function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) that you can use in order to generate an array made up of a range of numbers.

```
foreach (range(0, 12) as $value ) {
   echo('<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>');
}
```